# Best way to ensure bost sides of a Foreign Key are the same column type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a large database and we are heading into a project to change the int identity fields to BigInt or GUID.

I've changed a few but now I'd like to see if all the foreign keys have their opposite sides changed.

Yes I can go through them all but I'm hoping to find a script of some sort that will compare both sides and alert me if the column types don't match?

Comment: And what RDBMs are you using? Add the proper tag please.

Comment: Dump the structure sql and write a script?

Comment: If you change it to Bigint you should be fine but it you change it to GUID there are few issues. Its a all together different data type, Any views , functions , stored procedure might also need updating, GUID Primary Key will result in excessive page splits and will hurt the performance.

Comment: Instead of dumping the sql surely I can query something in the system tables to find both ends of a FK along with their type?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by butchering someone elses code.

```
SELECT C.TABLE_CATALOG [PKTABLE_QUALIFIER], 
   C.TABLE_SCHEMA [PKTABLE_OWNER], 
   C.TABLE_NAME [PKTABLE_NAME], 
   KCU.COLUMN_NAME [PKCOLUMN_NAME], 
   col.Data_Type,
   C2.TABLE_CATALOG [FKTABLE_QUALIFIER], 
   C2.TABLE_SCHEMA [FKTABLE_OWNER], 
   C2.TABLE_NAME [FKTABLE_NAME], 
   KCU2.COLUMN_NAME [FKCOLUMN_NAME], 
   RC.UPDATE_RULE, 
   RC.DELETE_RULE, 
   C.CONSTRAINT_NAME [FK_NAME], 
   C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME [PK_NAME], 
   CAST(7 AS SMALLINT) [DEFERRABILITY] 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU 
     ON C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col
     ON col.Table_Name =  C.TABLE_NAME
     AND col.Column_Name = KCU.COLUMN_NAME
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC 
     ON C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C2 
     ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = C2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        AND RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2 
     ON C2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        AND C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        AND KCU.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col2
     ON col2.Table_Name =  C2.TABLE_NAME
     AND col2.Column_Name = KCU2.COLUMN_NAME

WHERE  C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND col.Data_Type <> col2.Data_Type
```